# How to use StructureMap with OpenRasta

Tags: structuremap, openrasta

How do I use StructureMap with OpenRasta? Can I use it in place of the internal dependency resolver, or is it only possible to use it in conjunction with the built-in DI (i.e. for my own app's dependencies)?

Thanks

Comment: I'm asking this question because I can't find anything on the web, either on SO or in the OR documentation with any instructions or example code. Help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Structure map code is here](https://github.com/openrasta/openrasta-structuremap)

Build it then reference the library. Or you could git submodule it.

Then add the following code into your openrasta project

```
public class DependencyResolver : IDependencyResolverAccessor
{
    public IDependencyResolver Resolver
    {
        get { return new StructureMapDependencyResolver(ConfigureContainer()); }
    }


    public static IContainer ConfigureContainer()
    {
        var container = new Container();
        container.Configure(c => c.Scan(s =>
        {
            //normal SM registrations
        }));

        return container;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps

p.s Structure Map isn't officially supported, you're probably better off with Castle/Ninject.

Comment: This is helpful. Thanks! I am still having problems--a few dependencies are having errors resolving for some reason ("Ignoring constructor, following dependencies didn't have a registration:OpenRasta.OperationModel.Interceptors.IOperationInterceptor[]"). This is also happening to one of my own dependencies which is explicitly registered with SM. I'll keep messing with it...that's probably a different question.

Comment: BTW, I used a different syntax for configuring StructureMap. Instead of what you have above, I use the `container.Configure(c => c.For<...>(...).Use(x => ...))` syntax.